# Best practices of timeout after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js

I have implemented a timeout after my table is reloaded with new data, previously. I was having trouble on how to update my dom after ajax was called as I'm developing front end js on top of an analytical webapp. I've come to a solution to use timeout which will load the dom after its refreshed but I am unsure if this is the best practice as I have to preset the time and different view will have different queries and rendering time.

```
  $( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
     setInterval(function(){ 
        let update = d3.selectAll("#" + arcapi.chartId() + ' tbody td')
        update.filter(function(){
           if(this.innerHTML === 'Tier 2'){
             return true;
            }
        }).style('background-color','green');
     }, 2000); 
  });
```

Note: I could not directly update from ajax code right after ajaxComplete is because I don't have access ajax file. This is the best solution I have so far in 8 days. Do let me know your input and opinion.

Comment: Best practice is to hook into the completion event.  In your own $.ajax call it would be `.done` / `success:`.  In a 3rd party library, the library should provide a mechanism for this such as raising an event.  It sounds like your 3rd party library doesn't provide this event, so you can't follow "best practice" and will have to go with "the best you can in the situation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow below format as it mostly recommended among the `engineers`.
You could also read this [official document](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
        url: "YourRequestURL",
        error: function(){
            // This function would triggered when timeout occurred 
        },
        success: function(){
            //Your logic after success request 
        },
        timeout: 3000 // sets timeout 1 to 3 seconds is mostly used
    });
```

> Though there is no concrete rules for timeout but its recommended to
> set it between 1000-5000. However, as per your requirement it might change.

Hope this would help

Comment: is it possible to set 1ms  after timeout? like instantly update dom right after ajaxcomplete ?

Comment: The answer is you can .As you may know The default is 0 (technically it's undefined, but behaves as 0). This means no timeout in jQuery itself...if the browser has some timeout it's entirely possible you'll hit that.But As I said that is not feasible

Comment: Thanks , . was able to set timer to 0 but why is it recommended to set between 1000 - 5000. if i were to set it to 0 . it will instantly inject the custom js but will it affect the performance  of the UI in the long run ?

Comment: Well let me explain you more, suppose 30 user requesting in a same `server(URL)` there will be a queue on server request pool. So 29 request has to be in waiting state  beside if you don't set `timeout` request won't wait for server response as a result it will fail.But if you set `timeout` request will persist until the time finished. Hope you understand.